# Symfony 6 RedirectResponse url with query parameters issue

Tags: php, redirect, symfony6

I'm using Symfony 6.
I'm trying to get my user redirected after a successfull login to the same page he was on before requesting login. I store the initial url in the session.

on a twig template there is the login link :
{% set login_link = '/spotify/connection?initialUrl=' ~ app.request.requestUri %} <a href={{ login_link }}>

Here is the "onAuthenticationSuccess" method of my custom authenticator class :

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $initialUrl = $session->get('initialUrl');

        if(null !== $initialUrl)
        {

            return new RedirectResponse($initialUrl);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here's my issue :

I can get my variable $initialUrl to be the url I want (without the domain, with the parameters).
But :
This line

```
return new RedirectResponse($initialUrl);
```

redirects the user to the wrong page, the characters ?= seems to have changed to something like #; so no parameter is recognized

While this line :

```
return new RedirectResponse('/spotify/player?sessionId' . $sessionId);
```

Works fine... while obviously I checked and in both cases the string is the same...

Any idea why?

Read documentation, tried researches, finally got that manually making the url works... don't know why

Comment: Can you show us an example of `$initialUrl`, exactly as a debug statement shows it, and what URL you actual land on? Be precise, please, not vague as in "something like". Also, please verify that there is only _one_ redirect happening, by checking what the `Location` header of the response to the initial request contains.

Comment: @CBroe You're right, sorry for not being precise. result of a var_dump($initialUrl) : string(130) "/spotify/player?sessionId=978ac209885a3491285d9cc4bf18a364c11d65a7381cc6f696872d964da9270cbe4344c04266144532b6f0ae9362b33a632d". Url being redirected To : http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/player?sessionId&#61;978ac209885a3491285d9cc4bf18a364c11d65a7381cc6f696872d964da9270cbe4344c04266144532b6f0ae9362b33a632d

Comment: I confirm this is the first redirect. Another one happens after that but I know why it does.

Comment: `&#61;` is the numeric character reference for `=`, _in HTML_ - but in the URL context, they _don't_ have the same meaning. And the length of `/spotify/player?sessionId=978...632d`, of the value exactly as shown there in your comment, is 126 characters, and not 130, as the var_dump indicates. So, only logical conclusion - your `$initialUrl` value is _wrong_ already, it actually contains `&#61;` instead of a real `=` - which explains the four characters difference in length, but since the debug output was interpreted as HTML, it _shows_ as `=`.

Comment: OK great analysis. Tried with urlencode() and urldecode() and get the same results :   http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/player?sessionId&#61;978ac209885a3491285d9cc4bf18a364c11d65a7381cc6f696872d964da9270cbe4344c04266144532b6f0ae9362b33a632d and  string(130) "/spotify/player?sessionId=978ac209885a3491285d9cc4bf18a364c11d65a7381cc6f696872d964da9270cbe4344c04266144532b6f0ae9362b33a632d"

Comment: It's _not_ URL encoding, it is HTML encoding. You'd need to apply `html_entity_decode`, to get the `&#61;` transformed back into an actual `=` again. But that would just be fixing the symptom, rather than the actual problem - the value you stored into your session is _wrong_ to begin with, so it would make more sense to look at the other end of this, the way how that value gets into the session in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe updated the question with the twig template when the variable is first generated